# Flutter cryptography test case

Tags: flutter, dart, unit-testing

Why can not use `cryptography` on flutter test ?

```
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';

void main() {
  group("Test ECDH", () {
    test("generate shared secret", () async {
      final algorithm = Ecdh.p256(length: 32);
      final aliceKeyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();
    });
  });
}
```

i receive this error :

```
/opt/flutter/bin/flutter --no-color test --machine --start-paused test/custom_test.dart
Testing started at 9:24 PM ...

package:cryptography/src/dart/ecdh.dart 53:5  DartEcdh.newKeyPair
test/custom_test.dart 8:44                   main.<fn>.<fn>

UnimplementedError
```

this simple code does work on real application (web or mobile ...)
but i can not write test case for this library !

**Note: I test this code on Linux Ubuntu 22.04**

Comment: `cryptography` is a package in 2 halves. There are some pure Dart implementations and some 'faster' implementations that user Flutter method channels to the platforms native crypto methods. Check the source code and you see: `/// [Ecdh] (P256, P384, P521) implementation in pure Dart. Currently it throws [UnimplementedError] if you try to use it.` I.E. there's no pure Dart  version. Then look in the native side and it says: `/// [Ecdh] that uses platform APIs in Android, iOS, and Mac OS X.` Try running your tests on Mac instead.

Answer (score 1):

[DartEcdh class](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography.dart/DartEcdh-class.html)

> Ecdh (P256, P384, P521) implementation in pure Dart. Currently it
> throws UnimplementedError if you try to use it.

Apparently, the package doesn't work. (Tried on Mac too)

Maybe on a web version it could run, With the [Web Cryptography API](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/Ecdh-class.html).